# Packet Tracer 7.3.0 cannot be installed on Ubuntu

Tags: networking, package-management, dependencies, 20.04

I noticed that Ubuntu 20 Release, comes with many unmet dependencies with some of them already deprecated and almost impossible to install. I see this when I try to install Packet Tracer and it outputs that requires many dependencies that at the same time need to install other dependencies.

**Note**: If you have a solution, I hope it worked out for you on a VM with Ubuntu 20 before suggesting it.

```
m@m:~/Desktop$ sudo dpkg -i PacketTracer_730_amd64.deb
Selecting previously unselected package packettracer.
(Reading database ... 207479 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack PacketTracer_730_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking packettracer (7.3.0) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of packettracer:
 packettracer depends on libdouble-conversion1; however:
  Package libdouble-conversion1 is not installed.
 packettracer depends on qt-at-spi; however:
  Package qt-at-spi is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package packettracer (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.24-1ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.64ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.15-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 packettracer
```

EDIT: The main problem, is with qt-at-spi, libdouble-conversion1 I was able to install manually.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 qt-at-spi : Depends: libqt4-dbus (>= 4:4.8.0) but it is not installable
             Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.8~) but it is not installable
             Depends: libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.8~) but it is not installable
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same difficulty. After spending a few days googling and trying various suggestions, the following solved most of the problems.

1. Downloaded and installed libdoule-conversion1 from this link:
   https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libdouble-conversion1
2. Downloaded PacketTracer_730_amd64.deb from
   https://www.netacad.com/portal/resources/packet-tracer
3. Unpacked the .deb file and edited the file named *control* in the DEBIAN folder. I simply opened with text editor and deleted *qt-at-spi* from the "Depends: libdouble-conversion1, qt-at-spi" line, and saved, repacked as fixed.deb.

   Find detailed instructions [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/138188/easily-unpack-deb-edit-postinst-and-repack-deb).
4. Installed the fixed .deb.
5. Rebooted.

Now Packet Tracer can only be launched from the terminal, the shortcut icon is not working. I remember seeing a solution for that somewhere, but I don't really mind.

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to delete dependencies from packages. They're listed there for a reason, and deleting them could lead to a crash or other inconvenience.

Comment: @NonnyMoose That's generally correct, however in this case matraven is correct because the qt-at-spi package is not required by most of the features in Packet Tracer. I made an improved formatting edit to this answer in case the downvote is yours and you decide to retract. This is a big problem in 20.04, and this answer is unique among all the answers that I have read.

Comment: @karel My mistake. Does that mean that, technically, it should be an optional dependency?

Comment: @NonnyMoose Not having qt-at-sp installed disables one feature of Packet Tracer, so it is not an optional dependency even though the other features of Packet Tracer will work without it.

Comment: I worked with this. its working nicely no errors

Comment: They finally updated to version 5 of QT with Packet Tracer 7.3.1. At the beginning I had the dependency problem with dialog, but I ended up trying to install it. Finally, I installed the .deb and unpacked the usr/share/applications/*.desktop to the corresponding path within my system. Since it worked for Prasad, I mark this as Best Answer.